# AF Date Helper in swift could not find member ISO8601

Tags: ios, swift, struct, nsdate

I used cocoapod install AFDateHelper v2.0.1
And I have the following code

```
import AFDateHelper
import SwiftyJSON
struct MyStruct {
  var date: NSDate! 
  init(inJson : JSON) {
    self.date = NSDate(fromString: inJson["date_gmt"].string!, format: .ISO8601)
  }
}
```

and it said **cannot find member .ISO8601**, could anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was an issue of declaring the extension as public so the headers are available from the extension. I've update the repo and published a new pod version. Just run pod update and you should have it working.